# Cobordism: Reference Request.

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, cobordism

Where does one learn Cobordism theory - is there some canonical text or reference at the beginning graduate level? More general sources on modern differential topology (surgery etc.) are fine; any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: It's not a textbook, but I liked Dan Freed's lecture notes. http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C/index.html

Comment: Stong's book on cobordism theory is nice, but it's a level (just a bit) beyond the basics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if its good form to answer one's own question, but I have been recommended the book by Kosinski, Differential Manifolds by a member of the department. I'll see how I get on with it...

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228624/book-recommendation-for-cobordism-theory/228693#228693) before I knew this was already asked here. Anyway the references might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of differential topology, I learnt the theory of cobordism in an algebraic topology class. The first motivation was obtained from *Milnor's* classic book ***Characteristic Classes***. In section $17$, the oriented cobordism is introduced and bordism ring is also mentioned in later chapters.

Another reference I found to be very useful is ***Notes on Cobordism*** by *Haynes Miller*. It is very comprehensive and suitable for self-study.

Hope this helps.